# Drupal : How to remove default.css in the .module file?

Tags: css, drupal

Is it possible to remove the module/system/default.css file. I'd like to do this in the .module file and not in the template.php file.

My goal is to disable this style in my drupal website without manipulating a template/theme.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Bat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible. You can use `template_preprocess_page` in your custom module to whack Drupal's default CSS:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Get CSS array and remove selected stylesheets
  $css = drupal_add_css(); 
  unset($css['all']['module']['modules/system/defaults.css']);

  // Override Drupal styles
  $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
}
```

Because of Drupal's architecture, you'll almost certainly need to [set the module weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238) to something greater than your other installed modules to ensure that your preprocessor runs last and no other module will be adding CSS.